# Task top-up with asyncio

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.4, python-3.5, python-asyncio, aiohttp

In my project, I have a list to tasks that I execute with.

```
loop.run_until_complete(tasks)
```

However, there is an infinite number of tasks, so at the moment, I execute them in batches. Essentially, I have this:

```
def get_results(tasks):
    return [result for result in loop.run_until_complete(handle_tasks(tasks))]

while True:
    tasks = get_tasks()
    results = get_results(tasks)
```

I get a number of tasks, I lunch a regular function that uses a loop to perform these tasks asynchronously and returns the results.

This approach works, but I believe it can be improved.

Instead of doing batches of tasks, I would like to do some sort of task top-up.

Something like this:

```
while True:
    if current_tasks < max_tasks:
        new_tasks = get_tasks(max_tasks - current_tasks)
        add_tasks(new_tasks)
    current_tasks, results = stats_and_results()
```

I appreciate any ideas on how to approach this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: how about adding the tasks to `my_task_list` and then add when the list is less than a certain length? Then iterate the list from time to time to `cancel()` or prune `cancelled()` tasks?

Answer (score 3):

We had a similar problem and ended up writing a small "Pool" wrapper that takes jobs and run them with a predefined concurrency.

```
import asyncio
import sys


class Pool:
    def __init__(self, concurrency):
        self._sem = asyncio.BoundedSemaphore(concurrency)
        self.jobs = []

    async def __aenter__(self):
        return self

    async def __aexit__(self, *_):
        if len(self.jobs) > 0:
            await asyncio.wait(self.jobs)

    def put(self, coro):
        assert asyncio.iscoroutine(coro)
        async def wrapped():
            async with self._sem:
                await coro
        fut = asyncio.ensure_future(wrapped())
        self.jobs.append(fut)

    async def __aiter__(self):
        return self

    async def __anext__(self):
        try:
            coro = self.jobs.pop(0)
        except IndexError:
            raise StopAsyncIteration()
        else:
            return await coro
```

You can then use it this way:

```
async def main():
    pool = Pool(10)
    for task in get_tasks():
        pool.put(task)
    async for result in pool:
        print('got', result)
```

This will schedule all the task, run at most 10 of them concurrently and return the results as they come to the main() coroutine